# A word for a favor/debt that cannot be repaid

Tags: single-word-requests

I just feel like *unrepayable* isn't actually a word. Thesauri are not being helpful.

Consider a case in which someone saves your child's life. There is nothing you can ever do to pay them back for this favor.

What they have done for you is [word I'm looking for].

Comment: When you are unable to repay a debt to someone, you are said to be broke!  Or, as Ray Charles used to sing, "I'm busted!"  To be hoity toity about things, you could also say "I'm insolvent."  Or, as Wimpy in the Popeye cartoon strip used to say, "I will gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger today."  Of course, that locution simply delays the inevitable "I'm busted" come Tuesday!

Comment: Bankrupt is a word that means exactly this. (adj.) Declared in law unable to pay outstanding debts. (noun) A person unable to satisfy any just claims made upon him or her.

Comment: @RegDwighт, you're right. I have reworded both title and question to make the meaning clearer.

Comment: @rhetorician : the meaning I am looking for is in the body of the text: unrepayable, rather than my poorly written title. :)

Comment: @Jim this was actually not meant in the financial sense, although not clear in the original wording of my question.

Comment: @JordanReiter:  One possible word (I'm being serious this time) is "inestimable," meaning incapable of attaching a dollar value to, such as is the case when someone saves your life, or pays your mortgage until you get back on your feet, or gives you a desperately needed car for free, or donates a kidney to your daughter, or . . ..  An inestimable gift!

Comment: unrequitable: something that can not be returned in kind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What they have done for you is ***unrequitable***

from v. ***requite***: to make repayment or return for service, benefits, etc.

It can be found in sonnets and poems in the context of love and also of favours

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a more common expression which might express the deep gratitude one feels towards another person, a person who has saved your child's life. I would say to that man or woman

> Thank you—I am forever **indebted** to you.

Typical collocations with [indebted](http://collocations.enacademic.com/9175/indebted) are:

- deeply, greatly, much, profoundly
- eternally, forever

Comment: This collocation seems to be have been well established already some 250 years ago: *"Do so," said De Gondomar, "and I shall be **forever indebted** to you.."* The Tatler; or, Lucubrations of Isaac Bickerstaff, Esq - Vol. 1 - page 139 ([1764](http://books.google.com/books?id=oKNBAAAAYAAJ&q="forever+indebted"))

Answer (score 1):

"There is nothing that I can pay you for your deed. What you have done is **priceless**."

I can't think of anything else, but maybe this will get some ideas started for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the list of possible words by using qualifiers, if you'd prefer.

"I am unable to repay you."

"I cannot reimburse you."

If you're trying to go for a more emotional effect, you might say you are "forever indebted" to the person. I would use this last phrasing, personally, especially in the sample case you've given of saving someone's child.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "What they have done for you is invaluable".

Answer (score 0):

Some favors or mitzvahofs cannot be repaid.  The act of shoveling dirt into the grave of a loved one is a mitzvahof that cannot be repaid by the person being buried.

Comment: The OP is probably looking for an English word.

Answer (score 0):

Beholden : owing a debt that can never be repaid but emotional vs material

Comment: Hi Sara, this would benefit from a reference.  Please take the [tour] and see the [FAQ], and welcome to EL&U.